# xpcom vs2010 compile C++ XPCOM for FF extension error

Tags: visual-c++, xpcom

I'v used header.py and typelib.py to produce .h and .xpt correctly.

https://github.com/mozilla-services/services-central-legacy/tree/master/xpcom/sample

as a reference to compile in VC2010。

These are the errors below:

```
:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\nserror.h(119): error C2332: 'enum' : missing tag name
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\nserror.h(119): error C2236: unexpected 'class' 'nsresult'. Did you forget a ';'?
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\nserror.h(119): error C3381: 'nsresult' : assembly access specifiers are only available in code compiled with a /clr option
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\nserror.h(120): error C2516: 'uint32_t' : is not a legal base class
1>          d:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(23) : see declaration of 'uint32_t'
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\errorlist.h(4): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\errorlist.h(4): error C2864: 'nsresult::NS_OK' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\errorlist.h(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\errorlist.h(9): error C2864: 'nsresult::NS_ERROR_BASE' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\errorlist.h(11): error C2065: 'NS_ERROR_BASE' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\errorlist.h(11): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\errorlist.h(11): error C2864: 'nsresult::NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\errorlist.h(13): error C2065: 'NS_ERROR_BASE' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\xpcom\xulrunner-41.0.2.en-us.win32.sdk\xulrunner-sdk\include\errorlist.h(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   ...............
```

project property has been set following the xpcom example instructions.

No idea what happened. Really appreciate it if there is any help.

Comment: This is unreadable. Please format it first.

Comment: thank you for the attension ,but what do you mean by 'format it', it was the compile errors output using vs2010,the numbers is more than 100,I just get the first several here.